# Motor gets hot when using IRFZ44N to build a brushed speed controller

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

After working with a [TIP122](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/677721/build-a-speed-controller-for-3-7-v-brushed-dc-motor-720-using-bd139), I am now trying to use NFET IRFZ44N with the following components and diagram:

**Components:**

1. Arduino Nano 328p 5.
2. Potentiometer 10 kΩ
3. IRFZ44N
4. Diode 1N4007
5. Resistor 10 kΩ
6. Resistor 1 kΩ
7. Li-po battery 3.7 V 500 mAh
8. Cable/wires
9. 8520 coreless DC motor 3.7 V

**Diagram:**

[image: irfz44n 3.7v arduino]

**Here's the sketch:**

```C
    int analogPin = A0;   // potentiometer connected to analog pin 3
    int val = 0;         // variable to store the read value
    
    void setup()
    {
      pinMode(11, OUTPUT);   // sets the pin as output
      pinMode(11, LOW);   // sets the pin as output
    }
    
    void loop()
    {
      val = analogRead(analogPin);   // read the input pin
      analogWrite(11, val / 4);  // analogRead values go from 0 to 1023, analogWrite values from 0 to 255
    }
```

**PROBLEM:**

The 8520 coreless DC motor gets very hot in less than one minute when I spin the potentiometer from minumum to maximum. In one minute, there is a vibration of the motor when the potentiometer goes to the minimum value.

Of course there is something wrong with my project, but I have no idea what causing it, wiring and components or something I don't know.

Comment: Please draw a schematic with the built in tool by clicking edit and the schematic symbol. Also 1 kohm is a very high resistance for a gate drive. Try 10 ohm. What frequency are you running?

Comment: Okay, wait, I'll try again in an hour, please

Comment: 5V isn't enough for an IRFZ44N, either, but it seems that isn't the problem here. What is the actual problem? Coreless motors are not efficient; did you check the datasheet and see what power dissipation to expect?

Comment: The tiny brushes in the coreless motors in my "beginners" RC airplanes burned out soon and needed replacement after replacement The brushless motors on my newer RC airplanes last forever.

Comment: @Audioguru, sorry I don't understand what you mean. what are U going to say in this case?

Comment: I said that cheap brushed coreless motors have brushes so small that they soon burn out then the motor needs replacement over and over. The much better brushless motors in all of my RC airplanes last forever.

Comment: yes, you're right @Audioguru, here is one of my experiments since I'm a newb in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried all suggestions in comment but no good result. Finally, I **added a 100 µF capacitor to VCC and GND of Arduino (5 V)**, and remove the 1 kΩ in pin 11.

Here's **the update**:

[image]

and **the code**:

```
  void setup()   
  {   
  Serial.begin(9600);   
   pinMode(11,OUTPUT);  
   digitalWrite(11,LOW); // Normally LOW inthis pin   
   pinMode(A0,INPUT);  // 10k Potentiometer   
  }   
  void loop()   
  {   
  int s=analogRead(A0); // 10k Potentiometer   
  int z=map(s,0,1024,0,255);   
  Serial.println(z);   
  analogWrite(11,z);   
  }
```

Temp Result:

1. The motor is *not too hot* anymore.
2. I still have motor vibrations.
3. Motor speed cannot reach the max speed (I'm sure this is because of the vibration)

### UPDATE 2

To ensure this project, I solder all wires and connection to avoid getting wiring problem:

1. I change the thickness of the wire. I use all the same wires (28awg). Result = No heat.
2. I planned to remove the 10Ω to reach the MAX Throttle/speed. But, when the arduino was powered the motor started to spin in 6 seconds and stop - even though the potentiometer shows in min speed. Then I added 150Ω and It worked as expected !!! (based on [this article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQWLJ.png)).

By doing the two above, I finally didn't see the vibration!!!

**Noted:** I also **try using 4.2 LiPO battery** (8520/720 coreless DC motor can handle this based on its datasheet) and it spinned so fast (max throttle) without vibration and heat.

[image]

Time's to use this project for my DIY Arduino mini quadcopter!!! Thanks all!