# Is it okay using IRL520n without Resistor and Diode for DIY Brushed ESC/DC Motor

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, circuit-protection, drone

In this chance, I want to know further after doing some experiments related to Logical level MOSFET (IRL520N) as a speed controller for brushed 820 DC motor for micro Arduino Quadcopter.

I had done with many tutorials in youtube that I must use diode (e.g.1N4007/1N4001/1N5819) and resistor (10 kΩ /1 kΩ /200 Ω) and the problem were the same => **Can't reach max throttle**. (but, I ever used [IRFZ44N](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/679238/motor-gets-hot-when-using-irfz44n-to-build-a-brushed-speed-controller) and [TIP122](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/677721/build-a-speed-controller-for-3-7-v-brushed-dc-motor-720-using-bd139) with diode and resistor and it worked as I wished).

I also modified quadcopter firmware: multiwii 2.4, multiwii 2.3 and multiwii 1.8 and all was failed.

**FINALLY:**
Then **I remove all resistors and diode**, It finally reaches max throttle. **The point is that** The throttle must reach its maximum when I push the stick to the upper value.

**QUESTION:**
Is it okay if I don't use diode and resistor at the circuit? - besides, I don't find heat, the motors can spin perfectly and, I forgot, I add 100 uF capacitor in Vin+ and GND- in 3.7 V step-up converter.

[image: DIY brushed drone of Arduino]

Now, I've been waiting my new propellers since last night two propellers were broken after colliding my bedroom wall :)

**UPDATED (Brushed ESC CIRCUIT DIAGRAM):**
note: before removing (but can't reach max throttle):

[image]

**WORKING SCHEMATIC:**

[image]
(I hope I don't forget anything to design the circuit. I just designed it 5 minutes ago).

**ADD:**
LiPO Battery 3.7v 45C 1S 200mAh

Comment: Please provide a schematic, that shows where you placed a diode and a resistor.

Comment: The question is really hard to follow. Try to make it more clear. Use punctuation and complete sentences. I tried to edit it, but I'm afraid I couldn't understand what you were trying to say.

Comment: I just provided the circuit diagram (before and after). I also changed the title to the point of my question. THanks and please review, pleeease ... (edit: not 200 Ohm but 100 Ohm)

Comment: Please put a flyback diode across the motor.

Comment: Done! please review again. I hope I didnt miss anything. please let me know if I did.

Comment: Missing decoupling capacitors too.

Comment: done, all. I just provided decoupling 100uf 25v in working schematic design. Please review, thanks. (let me know if I missed again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no answer from my question, I finally do intensive experiments to many possibilities of projects.
For some reason, it could use n-mosfet without diode and resistor. But, I finally add them:

1. Diode: Freewheeling diode, to protect my circuit from abrupt reduction in the current flowing through the circuit.
2. Resistor: to be a switch-off and switch-on and, of course, to protect the MOSFET from high current.

[image: diy brushed esc by ArduJimmy]